# Jumping to the next character in a string without using the character's index in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to iterate through a string using characters instead of indices. For instance, for the string `s`. it would be something like:

```
for n in s:
   .........
   .........
```

where `n` is a character in the string. Is there any way I can refer to the next immediate character (from this string) in this 'for' loop, without making use of its index?

**Context**:
This is for the problem in LeetCode to convert Roman numerals into numbers, for which I wrote the code as follows:

```
class Solution:
    def romanToInt(self, s: str) -> int:
        '''
        Logic: 
        1. Create two cases: non on right is lesser than no on left and vice versa 
        2. If right > left, subtract left from right and add to value. Skip one position in loop. 
        3. If left > right, simply add value of left to total, and move to next in loop.     
        
        '''
        roman = {'I': 1, 'V': 5, 'X': 10, 'L': 50, 'C': 100, 'D': 500, 'M': 1000}
        val = 0 # value of roman numeral 
        
        for n in s:
            if roman[n] > roman[n+1]:
                val += roman[n]
                n = n + 1
                return n 
            elif roman[n] < roman[n+1]:
                val += roman[n+1]-roman[n]
                n = n + 2
                return n 
            return val
```

which obviously returns an error every time I try to add a character `n` to an integer `1`. Which is why I am looking for a way to iterate chracterwise rather than using the indices.

Thank you!

Comment: I think both answers does not answer what you are looking for. Which means, your question needs some clarification. If I get you right, you want to access i+1'th (or i-1'th) element of the string in the for loop where i is the current index. Correct ?

Comment: yep, that's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think what you are looking for is making any sense...
The best approach i can think of is like this..

```
for i, n in enumerate(s):
    next_char = s[min((i+1, len(s)-1))]
    # do your stuff
```

Comment: oh cool. Yes this helps.

Comment: A slight correction here, I think. It should be `len(s)-1` otherwise index would go out of range.

Comment: Oh right... fixed! ^.^

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new string with the characters offset by 1, zip that with the original string, then iterate over the resulting list of tuples.

```py
for this_char, next_char in zip(s, list(a)[1:] + [None]):
    # next_char will be None in the last iteration
    pass
```

Explanation

```py
# convert the string to a list
offset_string = list(a)

# shift the list by one via slicing
offset_string = offset_string[1:]

# since the list is 1 element shorter than the string, add a `None` to the end so we still can have the last character
offset_string = offset_string + [None]

for this_char, next_char in zip(s, offset_string):
    pass
```